# rails: link_to to pass list of selected checkboxes into params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, parameters, link-to

I am not sure what the correct approach is for my situation:

I want to create a link_to pushing all checkboxes with value="1" into an array, or individually if array is not possible, but I am at a loss of how to express that?

```
<% @cards.each do |card| %>
    <%= check_box("#{card.name}", card.id, {checked: true}) %><%= "#{card.name}" %>
<% end %>
```

(Rails 4.2)

Comment: `link_to` is just an `a` tag. You can build the params within its `onclick` event I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of dead ends, trying to make it a 'clean' solution I ended up with this very dirty approach. But as they say, done is better than perfect:

Create a `link_to` that would include all the cards, but add one additional params: `user_selected_cards = ""`.

Create a javascript that listens to for checking/unchecking of the checkboxes and reads the id associated with that specific checkbox. Then take that incoming info and add or remove it to the actual url that the link_to generates by finding the `user_seletected_cards=` portion in the url and add or remove the id depending on if isn't or already is added to the list after the equal sign.

Comment: I agree; that's pretty bad.